# In which manner could we update our data warehouse based on the status changes of already transferred records in live DB?

Tags: sql, data-warehouse

I have a E-Commerce website which I want to create a data-warehouse out of its relational database. Consider I have a payment table in my relational database, each payment has status which would change during payment process (Imagine these status could be: New, Processing, Succeed, Failed). Now I want to have a PaymentFactTable in my warehouse so that each record in it represents "All Payments in a specific hour with specific status" then on each I have some facts like Total Payment Amount or Total Gateway Interest. But there is where my problem raises. Imagine my ETL service has transferred and grouped payments of an hour into my warehouse, but these payments would change their status during next hour, so ... what should I do? and how should I update payment groups in warehouse, one problem is I don't have any clue in warehouse to find and update the group of changed payment. And the other question is how warehouse should be informed about these status changes in order to update its data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are tracking a process flow here. In a dimensional data model, Ralph Kimball recommends that to do this, you should use what is called an "Accumulating Snapshot" fact table.

Essentially, here's an example of what the table would look like:

```
PaymentAccFactID        Int
PaymentNaturalKey       Int (the "natural identifier" of a transaction)
CustomerDim             Int
PaymentTypeDim          Int 
... additional dims as needed ...
NewStatusTS             Timestamp (ansi timestamp)
NewStatusHourDim        Int
NewStatusFlag           SmallInt
ProcessingStatusTS      Timestamp 
ProcessingStatusHourDim Int
ProcessingStatusFlag    SmallInt
SucceededStatusTS       Timestamp
SucceededStatusHourDim  Int
SucceededStatusFlag     SmallInt
FailedStatusTS          Timestamp
FailedStatusHourDim     Int
FailedStatusFlag        SmallInt
```

Every time you pull ETL, pull any records that have changed since the last pull, and modify the status accordingly. The `HourDim` fields would connect to your Day by Hour dimension - or you can create a second set of fields to hook to your Day (date) dimension for each status, leaving the first just pointing to your Time of Day dimension.

As the payments flow through the process from New to Processing to Succeeded/Failed, you would update the row on the accumulating snapshot to reflect this. I include the `Flag` columns to make it easy to sum up payments in certain statuses as of certain times. You can also add a `CurrentStatusDim` field to connect to your status dimension if you want to fiter on that as well. If your ETL detects that you've moved from New to Succeeded / Failed in the next hour, then you know it moved to "Processing" in that hour as well, but if you aren't tracking events on payments, you won't be able to know the specific time that it occurred.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, with considering your payment fact table, my problem is I don't get each payment from live db into warehouse but What I actually do in each ETL process is to bring groups of payments, I mean each record in my payment fact table is like yours but it's not related to one payment in live db, it's a group of payments in 1 hour who have same dimensions, please tell me if the problem is the design and I should revise it?!

Comment: @MohsenAsfia Does the source system track payments individually, or does it group them for you? You need to *declare the grain* of your facts - and it should typically be at the lowest level possible so you can roll up transactions across all dimensions. If you are pre-aggregating your data in your ETL, it will make the ability to track individual payments very difficult. How much data are you dealing with on a daily / weekly / monthly basis?

Comment: My source system track payments individually, I have nearly 70000 payments each day and respectively almost 500000 each weak and 2 million payments each month. Because of this great deal of data we are dealing with, we are force to some how do grouping job in our payments when we want to do the ETL process so that we could have a better performance when we make query in our data warehouse. But doing this makes update of each payment group in warehouse (because of a payment further status change) nearly impossible, so what do you suggest in this situation?

Comment: @MohsenAsfia 2 million / month isn't that large at all. You should easily be able to pull 70,000 records in less than a minute or two, even assuming you have relatively cheap hardware. Are you reading via a web service or something that returns data row by row?? Even assuming you have 500 byte records (which i highly doubt), one month of data is less than a gigabyte.

Comment: @MohsenAsfia I would recommend that you take a look at Ralph Kimball's book [The Data Warehouse ETL Toolkit](http://www.amazon.com/The-Data-Warehouse-ETL-Toolkit/dp/0764567578), it contains lots of practical techniques for getting data out of source systems. With only 70k rows / day, you could probably even build an hourly ETL process that pulls over the  3000 rows per hour.

Comment: Yeah you`re right extracting just 3000 rows per hours is not a big deal, but if we did not group the payments in the time of extraction, later when we would run a query on warehouse imagine we should run it on nearly 30 million records!! which is time consuming and takes too much power of warehouse db, while if we do the grouping job the number of records would be 5 or 6 million which could boost our query performance, don`t you agree?

Comment: @MohsenAsfia If your warehouse DB is slow, you can build aggregates in the warehouse based on that grouping, rather than building the aggregates in the source system. You can set up jobs to update the aggregates as needed (I would expect that payments over a day old wouldn't be changing much if at all), and still get good query performance. You can also look into indexing and table partitioning, perhaps by day or week, so you aren't dealing with too much data at once.

Comment: @N West Thank you for your kind and helpful responses which helped me so much

Answer (score 0):

I have been in your situation. Here's what I did and it worked really well:

We made the decision that at midnight "the books were closed" for the day and everything was sent as-is to the warehouse. Whatever was completed for the day stayed completed at the warehouse and was never changed there. If a refund or similar happened later, that counted as a new transaction for the warehouse.

This worked for the accounting department because it meant never "rewriting history", which they hate. It was simple for the IT guys too, because we only had to deal with data a day at a time, and never had to update the warehouse data (we only ever inserted daily).

If daily is too course grained for you, you could do this using an hourly basis instead, but you'll probably find that most businesses are happy with daily.

If the size of the data is too large to do daily, you could pre-process those transactions you  knew were final for the day *before* the day ended (we had to do this for some particularly high volume transactions that had post-mid-night timing-critical reporting requirements)

Comment: But That could decrease precise of our queries in warehouse, consider a query with this definition: "Get Me All Payments of a Specific Gateway which remain in 'New' Status" (I mean all payments in that customers went to payment gateway but they don't continue to complete the payment) -- imagine our ETL operation is hourly basis. Now what if we had a payment in late part of an hour and naturally at first its status is 'New' but in 2 minutes (next hour) its status became 'succeed' so if we insert two records in warehouse for that payment, our query result would consider that payment as 'New'